# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int' with switch statement

Tags: c#, numbers

I'm very new to c#, and I'm trying to make a simple number-guessing game, basically the user enters their guess and if the guess is the higher than the number, the system will display the it's higher or lower.

this is the code:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;

Random random = new Random();   

int num = random.Next(0,101);

Console.WriteLine("This is a number guessing game between 1 - 100 ! ");
Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess : ");
int respond = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



switch (respond) {

    case respond > num: Console.WriteLine("");
        break;

    case respond < num: Console.WriteLine("");
        break;
    case respond == num  : Console.WriteLine("You won !");
        break;


}




Console.WriteLine("You won !");
Console.WriteLine("It took you " + tries + " tries");



Console.ReadKey();
```

the problem comes in this part, the switch :

```
switch (respond) {

    case respond > num: Console.WriteLine("");
        break;

    case respond < num: Console.WriteLine("");
        break;
    case respond == num  : Console.WriteLine("You won !");
        break;
}
```

I always get an error when trying to compare 'respond' and 'num', specifically, this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'

does anyone know how to fix it?

I tried changing the place and the variable respond, same with 'num' nothing seemed to work.

Comment: The cases in switch cases need to be a constant value (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc). Having respond > num is not a constant value. Replace the switch case with either an if else chain or use pattern matching in *switch expressions*.

Comment: Change the switch with a if... else if... else stamenents... Switch just accept int types or enum and respond > num is a boolean expression

Comment: As a side note, `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` is an exception waiting to happen. You should never trust user input. Instead of using `Convert.ToInt32`, you should be using `int.TryParse` that will not throw exceptions but only return false if the string can't be parsed to an integer.

Answer (score 5):

The error you encountered is because you are trying to use a switch statement with conditions that evaluate to boolean values (`respond > num`, `respond < num`), but the switch statement expects constant integral expressions.

In this case, you should use an `if else` statement to compare the values. Like:

```
using System;

Random random = new Random();
int num = random.Next(0, 101);

Console.WriteLine("This is a number guessing game between 1 - 100!");
Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ");
int respond = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (respond > num)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
else if (respond < num)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You won!");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
static int Compare(int num, int respond) => num < respond ? -1 : num > respond ? 1 : 0;
Console.WriteLine(Compare(num, respond) switch
{
    -1 => "Less Than",
    1 => "Greater Than",  
    _ => "Bingo"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want compare dynamic value in a case statement of a switch, like  this:

```
switch (respond)
{
    case int x when (x>num):
        Console.WriteLine("number to high");
        break;
    case int x when (x < num):
        Console.WriteLine("number to low");
        break;
    case int x when (x == num):
        Console.WriteLine("You won!");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Switch statements take Bools not integers. Thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: That's news to me.